# scrollview in android alert dialog

Tags: android, checkbox, scrollview, android-alertdialog

i write android apps. i have a button, when click on it, an alert Dialog appear. this Dialog have 12 check box in it. my problem is that all the check boxes overlap.
my activity is:

```
public class Get_CheckboxActivity extends Activity {

private String result="";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_report);

    View checkBoxView = View.inflate(this, R.layout.checkbox, null);
    final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) checkBoxView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
    final CheckBox checkBox1 = (CheckBox) checkBoxView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox1);
    final CheckBox checkBox2 = (CheckBox) checkBoxView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox2);
    final CheckBox checkBox3 = (CheckBox) checkBoxView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox3);
    final CheckBox checkBox4 = (CheckBox) checkBoxView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox4);
    final CheckBox checkBox5 = (CheckBox) checkBoxView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox5);
    final CheckBox checkBox6 = (CheckBox) checkBoxView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox6);
    final CheckBox checkBox7 = (CheckBox) checkBoxView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox7);
    final CheckBox checkBox8 = (CheckBox) checkBoxView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox8);
    final CheckBox checkBox9 = (CheckBox) checkBoxView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox9);
    final CheckBox checkBox10 = (CheckBox) checkBoxView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox10);
    final CheckBox checkBox11 = (CheckBox) checkBoxView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox11);

    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            result=result.concat(checkBox.getText().toString());
        }
    });
    checkBox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            result=result.concat(checkBox1.getText().toString());
        }
    });
    checkBox2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            result=result.concat(checkBox2.getText().toString());
        }
    });
    checkBox3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            result=result.concat(checkBox3.getText().toString());
        }
    });
    checkBox4.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            result=result.concat(checkBox4.getText().toString());
        }
    });
    checkBox5.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            result=result.concat(checkBox5.getText().toString());
        }
    });
    checkBox6.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            result=result.concat(checkBox6.getText().toString());
        }
    });
    checkBox7.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            result=result.concat(checkBox7.getText().toString());
        }
    });
    checkBox8.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            result=result.concat(checkBox8.getText().toString());
        }
    });
    checkBox9.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            result=result.concat(checkBox9.getText().toString());
        }
    });
    checkBox10.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            result=result.concat(checkBox10.getText().toString());
        }
    });
    checkBox11.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            result=result.concat(checkBox11.getText().toString());
        }
    });

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        builder.setMessage("title")
               .setView(checkBoxView)
               .setCancelable(false)
               .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       Intent intent = new Intent (Get_CheckboxActivity.this,Add_ReportActivity.class);
                      // intent.putExtra("ckeck_res",result );
                       startActivity(intent);                          }
               })
               .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                   }
               }).show();
}
}
```

and  checkbox.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkbox"
    style="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="c12"
    android:layout_margin="5dp" />
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkbox1"
    style="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:text="c11"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp" />
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkbox2"
    style="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:text="c10"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp" />
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkbox3"
    style="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:text="c9"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp" />
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkbox4"
    style="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:text="c8"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp" />
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkbox5"
    style="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:text="c7"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp" />
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkbox6"
    style="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:text="c6"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp" />
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkbox7"
    style="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:text="c5"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp" />
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkbox8"
    style="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:text="c4"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp" />
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkbox9"
    style="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:text="c3"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp" />
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkbox10"
    style="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:text="c2"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp" />
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkbox11"
    style="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:text="c1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp" />
</FrameLayout>
```

when i use scrollview, it stoped! is there any way?

Comment: create a scrollview & one child layout then put all your checkboxes in that child layout.. better use relative or linear layout

Comment: Check your layout. There is not ScrollView as Root Element. Put the ScrollView as Root Element and use Get Layout Inflater instead of View.inflate. Hope it will work for you.

Comment: i put scrollView after <fragment> tag, but it force closed!